# errordocument not working when .htaccess rewriterules removing "index.php"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, errordocument

I am trying to use my .htaccess to modify my URL from:

```
<myURL>/index.php/something/something
```

to

```
 <myURL>/something/something
```

However, while adding the `rewriterules` in the `.htaccess` file, the `ErrorDocument` directives are not being followed. Is there any way that I can achieve this, while removing the "index.php"?

The contents of my .htaccess are:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
   ErrorDocument 404 "message failed"
</IfModule>
```

My httpd.conf contains:

```
<Directory /var/www/<myURL>...>
allow from all
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
AllowOverride all
order allow,deny
</Directory>
```

I have been trying to fix this for days. Any help is greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: I am pretty certain the correct spelling is `ErrorDocument`, not `errordocument`...

Comment: Apart from that I do not understand how that is meant to work: you rewrite every request to something that does not exist in the physical file system to your router script `index.php`. So how should ever a http status 404 get raised?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I will fix the spelling of "errordocument", however the problem is still not resolved. Is there any way I can rewrite the URL, removing "index.php" and reverting to 404 in case there is a page missing? Or does everything have to be done in PHP?

Comment: @Arkascha "ErrorDocument" is case-insensitive.

Comment: Revert to the error document in case _what_ is missing? You rewrite _everything_ to `index.php`, which most likely _always_ exist.

Comment: @arkascha By default the website would contain "index.php" and if the "index.php" file failed to return anything, then the 404 error would be returned. However, in this case as you specified all connections are routed to "index.php". Is there any way in which if "index.php" does not return a page I can raise a 404 error? Or is that not possible with apache.

Comment: OK, sure, you can use the `http_response_code()` function (http://php.net/manual/de/function.http-response-code.php). That does not work for you?